# Firefox font shown double layer compare chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

[image: My firefox browser version is 46. some font has display double layer in most of websites.i attached one website screen. it is Firefox issue or font issue?. it's work fine for other system firefox browsers and other browsers ie. chrome safari. please give any solution for this issue]

My firefox browser version is 46. some font has display double layer in most of websites.i attached one website screen. it is Firefox issue or font issue?. it's work fine for other system firefox browsers and other browsers ie. chrome safari. please give any solution for this issue

Comment: is this the issue with just 1 font or a few that you tried ?

Comment: I just add only one font

Comment: I will advise you to check with another font or if you can share the details of the font and from which font hosting website did you get this..

Comment: I am currently using Helvetica Neue font family. and issue not it this site only. lot of live sites have same issue.

Comment: maybe there is some rendering issue of the font with firefox and Mac and it works well with webkit based browsers..

Comment: Yes it work fine in webkit browsers. but we need fix Firefox browser. if any solution

Comment: just check with the font hosting service if they provide the css for you to use directly or go to font-squirrel and generate the css for the font and then try.. unfortunately that's all I know and if it doesn't work then I have no clue..

Comment: Which platform? Also, have you cleared the cache? And you say this happens with a lot of live sites, so can you give an example of an url where it happens?

Comment: Just find a different font. It's nothing special or fancy, so shouldn't be too hard to find a similar one. Try Google Fonts, they are easy to implement

Comment: This live site also same issue https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/

Comment: All Helvetica Neue font family used site get same problem. in windows platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Uninstall Helvetica Neue font family in my system. it working fine. i use only font face method.